# Applying Material UI styleOverrides at the component-level with styled()

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, storybook

I'm not sure if this is possible or not, after looking at Material UI's documentation on [How to Customize](https://mui.com/customization/how-to-customize/), but I'm trying to isolate `styleOverrides` for a given component using `styled()` rather than applying a lot of overrides within a global theme file.

Currently, my theme file looks something like this, with some typography and palette overriding Material UI's default theme:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: { ...
  },
  typography: { ...
  }
});
```

When I use a Chip component (rendered in Storybook currently) and pass in `success`, `primary`, `secondary`, etc. into the `color` prop, the corresponding theme colors are applied. However, when I try to override the theme files, using `styled()`, the colors defined in the theme are still being applied - as opposed to my overrides defined. My component file looks like the following:

```
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import MuiChip, { ChipProps } from '@mui/material/Chip';
    
const Chip = styled(MuiChip)<ChipProps>(({ theme }) => ({
  colorPrimary: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.light
  },
  colorSecondary: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.light
  }
}));

export default Chip;
```

Comment: what version of material-ui were/are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom variant and define your own styles to it

```
const theme = createTheme ({
          components : {    
               MuiButton : {  
                    variants : [ 
                           { props : { variant : 'YouVarName'}, 
                             style: { //..your styles } ,  
                                                             },},
```

Comment: My goal is to try to get away from defining and overriding the theme for each component customization. I would like to apply styleOverrides at the component-level with `styled()` or even `sx` if possible.